# Summing and averaging data in openrefine or libre office

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, openrefine

I have data in this format:

| Number | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | John | 2020-01-01 |
| 12 | Ann | 2020-01-01 |
| 9 | John | 2020-01-02 |
| 10 | Ann | 2020-01-02 |

How can I do a sum of values of Number cell from all rows with certain name and how to do average value for each name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LibreOffice Calc, for example if `10` is in cell A2:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B5;"=John";A2:A5)
=AVERAGEIF(B2:B5;"=John";A2:A5)
```

Result:

```
19
9.5
```